# Does SENTRI include TSA Pre-Check for Non-US citizens?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, tsa, tsa-precheck, sentri

Does SENTRI include TSA Pre-Check for Non-US citizens that are not from one of the following: Colombia, the United Kingdom, Germany, India, Panama, Singapore, South Korea, Switzerland, and Mexico?

Answer (score 1):

[No](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/) (click "Learn More" under SENTRI), unless they're a US permanent resident:

> Access to TSA Pre✓® expedited security lanes at airports within the U.S. and U.S territories for U.S. Citizens and U.S. lawful permanent residents.

However the list of citizenships or nationalities that can get Global Entry (and thus both SENTRI and TSA Pre access) is slightly different than the one in your question. [The current list](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/eligibility) is: Argentina, India, Colombia, UK, Germany, Panama, Singapore, South Korea, Switzerland, Taiwan, Mexico.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. Foreign non-residents can also use the TSA Pre lanes if they have Global Entry benefits (I was one of those once). [SENTRI members get Global Entry and TSA Pre benefits if their nationality/status is one that would allow them to apply for GE](https://cbpcomplaints.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-969?language=en_US). There is hence a list of nationalities (those allowed to apply for GE) for which SENTRI would include TSA Pre, though I don't think the list in the question is accurate.

Comment: The way I understand the website is that foreign non-residents from the list of nationalities are allowed to apply for Global Entry, and Global Entry can allow SENTRI access with vehicle registration and [TSA Pre access](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/tsa-precheck). However, the specific language is "Global entry members are eligible to participate in TSA Precheck. U.S. citizens and U.S. lawful permanent residents enrolled in NEXUS or SENTRI are also eligible to participate in TSA Precheck, as well as Canadian citizens who are members of NEXUS."

Comment: @Dennis In other words, Global Entry members (who can be foreign non-residents if they have a nationality on the list) can get TSA Pre. But SENTRI members only get TSA Pre if they're US citizens or permanent residents. I'd be happy to be wrong about this, but everything I've seen on official government sources says that SENTRI doesn't include TSA Pre for non citizens/residents. I agree there's a list of nationalities that can get GE and therefore both SENTRI and TSA Pre at the same time though, and that list is slightly larger than the question. I'll clarify that.

Comment: That conflicts with the link I included, which says "Approved SENTRI members are able to use the Global Entry kiosks when re-entering the United Sates by air and TSA Pre-check, as long as they meet the citizenship requirements for Global Entry", i.e. the GE list is the SENTRI list and is not limited to US citizens and LPRs. I know a Mexican who has SENTRI and uses the GE kiosks when he flies, I emailed him asking about TSA Pre but he hasn't responded yet.

Comment: My friend finally got back to me. He thinks SENTRI membership might actually be limited to US people and Mexican residents (of any nationality?). I've not seen that documented anywhere but there's a logic to it. He says he gets TSA Pre, and thinks that while not all SENTRI members get GE benefits, those that would otherwise qualify for GE directly do. [This document](http://tiny.cc/ro3iuz) confirms that Mexican nationals (at least) do get GE benefits after "a thorough risk assessment by the Mexican goverment", which is what they would require for a GE membership.

Comment: P.S. I don't think the assertion that all GE members get SENTRI access is correct. Using the SENTRI lanes requires an RFID card [but only US people and Mexican national GE members](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/card) (plus NEXUS members) are provided with one.